# How can I get these two divs to appear close to each other vertically?

Tags: html, css

a bit new to web development so bear with me. As you can see in the Codepen I've made [here](https://codepen.io/RBrNx/pen/VmEREX), I am developing a prototype messaging client. I'd like the Chat Name and the Preview Text to be one under the other, really close like in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCKEa.jpg). I'd also like to have another Div/Span at the end of the the button that will have some inner text as well, like in the image where it says "Now".

Here's my CSS for reference, how can I get the two (three, really) divs to be in the correct place.

```
.nav-side-menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  border-right: 1px solid #484848;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #484848;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  line-height: 75px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
}
.chat-header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    line-height: 75px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
}

.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: none;
}

.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-side-menu ul :not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li :not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  /*font-family: FontAwesome;*/
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  background-color: #3ab795;
}

.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 29px;
  padding-bottom: 29px;
  padding-right: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #484848;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #3ab795;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#searchbox{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #484848;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.search-menu{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #484848;
    padding: 5px;
}

.chat-box{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60px;
    left: 20%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border-top: 1px solid #484848;
}

#message-box{
    width: 95%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #484848;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.send-message{
    background-color: #3ab795;
    width: 3%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}

.send-message:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

.send-message:active{
    background-color: #29a281;
}

.preview-text{
    font-size: 11px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    color: #484848;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .brand {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 50px !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.nano { height: 85%; }
.nano .nano-pane   { background: #888; }
.nano .nano-slider { background: #111; }
```

Comment: where is ur html?

Comment: @MandarSant Whoops sorry forgot to add them to the post. Added a Codepen and an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://codepen.io/djkantoci/pen/KNGYbv

Change `line-height` to 1.5 (or some other value, but don't use pixels).
Add some `padding-right` to `li` (to make space for time text), append time and add `position: absolute` to that time div (don't forget to make `li` element relative)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty much right. Because of line height, that element getting so much height. Please have a look at below code.

```
    .nav-side-menu ul,
    .nav-side-menu li{
        line-height: normal;
    }
    .nav-side-menu li> div {
        padding: 5px 12px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the line height on your `nav-side-menu` elements

```
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```